# How to transition to SCNView from a SKView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, transition

Hey ok I have a `UIView` just the standard default controller but then I have a `SCNView` in another .swift file so I can transition from a standard `UIViewController` to a `SKScene` but I can't transition from a `SKScene` to `SCNcene` the catch is that in my code

```
 class PlayController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{


    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let skScene = scnView.overlaySKScene

    scnView.overlaySKScene = skScene
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    scnView.scene = FieldScene
    scnView.delegate = self

    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnView.showsStatistics = false
```

the controller that I'm trying to transition to as shown above starts off as a UIViewController and then further down the line get put as a `SCNView`. 
in this line of code let scnView = self.view as! `SCNView` but when I'm trying to transition from the `SKScene` to this scene how would i do that in code Swift?

the controller that I'm starting on looks like this below

```
import iAd
import UIKit
import GameKit
import SceneKit
import StoreKit
import SpriteKit
import QuartzCore
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox

//============================================================
class MainMenuController: SKScene, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
}
```

Comment: You also need to add parenthesis to FieldScene so scnView.scene = FieldScene()

Answer (score 3):

### overlaySKScene

The implementation of `let skScene = scnView.overlaySKScene` and `scnView.overlaySKScene = skScene` should be changed because they're ineffectual

Create SKScene object:`let overlayScene = SKScene(size: CGSizeMake(200, 200))`.

Set the position for your base object:`base.position = CGPointMake(75, 0)`.

Add base object to scene:`overlayScene.addChild(base)`.

Set scene to overlay:`scnView.overlaySKScene = overlayScene`.

### Transitioning

You can add a transition by calling the view's **presentScene:withTransition:incomingPointOfView:completionHandler:** method.

```
    sceneView.presentScene(nextSceneToLoad(),
    withTransition:skTransition,
    incomingPointOfView:nil, completionHandler:nil)
```

Another example.

```
let transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(.Right, duration: 1.0)
self.sceneView?.presentScene(SCNScene(), withTransition: transition, incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

[overlaySKScene API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524051-overlayskscene)

[presentScene API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1520090-presentscene)